# как отменить бесплатный план на гитхабе?

Tags: github

Хотел удалить аккаунт с гитхаба. когда появляется окно с подтверждением удаления кнопка недоступна, на ней написано:
"Cancel plan and delete this account."
Скриншот:
[image]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой? Пожалуйста, отзовитесь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это их обычная формулировка. Просто введите пароль, логин и в среднее поле ввода текст `delete my account`.

Comment: попробую сделать

Comment: все сработало! :)

Comment: @Lololoshka тогда не стесняйтесь отмечать ответ как верный ;)